# ggplot2 : different spacing for categorical x

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a vulgarization graph, I am comparing different proportion for several overlapping groups (stupid example: man and woman and small / tall).

By default, obviously, all x ticks are evenly spaced-out.

For clearer visualization, man and woman should be close together while further from small and tall (which should be close also).

```
dat <- data.frame(value=runif(6)*10,
                  lab=c('1man','2woman','3small','4tall','5sick','6healthy'))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=lab, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.5),size=4) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=14,face="bold"))+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

I know there is something to do around facet_wrap and facet_grid but it would yield other problems (e.g., the groupings would all have the same width while having a different number of categories.

Any idea to setup space of the categorical X directly in the plot ?

Comment: Unless you want to do something really hacky, such as make these numeric spaced non-continuously and then disguise it with the labeling, you can use `facet_grid` with `space = "free_x"`. That will make the facets' widths set based on the number of categories in each

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel like there should be a good SO post on this already but couldn't find one so I'll toss out a `facet_grid` solution. If you set `scales = "free_x"`, the facet panels will have their limits set independent of one another, and adding `space = "free_x"` lets those panels have their size set based on the amount of space their values take up. To illustrate, I added an additional group.

Collapse the groups into a variable of categories to use for facetting (I like `forcats::fct_collapse`). Assuming you don't actually want the category labels, I dropped the strip labelling; you can mess around with panel spacing as well. Beyond that, I'm cutting out ggplot detail that doesn't pertain to the specific issue.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(value=runif(7)*10,
                  lab=c('1man','2woman','3small','4tall','5sick','6healthy', "7chronic"))

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(category = forcats::fct_collapse(lab, 
                                          sex = c("1man", "2woman"),
                                          size = c("3small", "4tall"),
                                          health = c("5sick", "6healthy", "7chronic")))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = lab, y = value)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(category), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(1, "cm"),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I think this is the way that you are 'supposed to' deal with this design issue from the point of view of ggplot2. +1

Comment: Using `fct_collapse` is cool. You could also, instead of facetting, simply use `aes(x = category, group/color/fill/etc = lab)`, (but of course the x axis would then not exactly look like the OP requested)

Comment: @Tjebo I don't think that's really comparable. You could set x = category and color = lab, then dodge the points, but then you lose the x-axis markers for lab and have a color encoding (and legend) that isn't really necessary since you could have encoded the same information more simply. From a readability standpoint, that's a pretty bad move. The category variable was one I added as a dummy in order to place the groups—it wasn't something the OP had in their data, so I wouldn't want to give it explicit labels if not needed

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky way to add space by converting `lab` to a factor with dummy levels, then giving them blank labels. There are still tick marks in the spaces and it doesn't bring the other values closer together. I recommend the `facet_grid` method with theming to get the spacing the way you want it.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  value=runif(6)*10,
  lab=factor(c('1man','2woman','3small','4tall','5sick','6healthy'),
     levels=c('1man','2woman', 'space1', '3small','4tall', 'space2','5sick','6healthy')))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=lab, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE,
                   labels=c('1man','2woman', '', '3small','4tall', '','5sick','6healthy'))
```

[image]